# Answering Queries on Binary array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, intervals

Given a binary array of length **<=10^5** and almost equal number of queries. Each query is given by two integers **(l,r)** for each query we have to computer the total number of consecutive **0**'s and **1**'s in the range **[l,r]**.

If **n** is the length of the array then **1 <= l < r <= n**.

For example:

if the binary array (**1**-indexed) is "**011000**" and say there are 5 queries:

> 1 3
>   5 6
>   1 5
>   3 6
>   3 4

Then the required answer is

> 1
>     1
>   2
>    2
>    0

I am aware that this can be solved by a linear time (worst case) algorithm for each query but due to the large number of queries it's not feasible.

Just wondering which is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: This smells like homework. Have you even attempted this yourself?

Comment: @ Bojangles: I can assure you that this is not a homework and this is not as trivial as it may seem. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for. Take the last two queries as an example. The elements in the range [3,6) are "000". There are *three* consecutive zeroes, so why is the answer 2? The elements in the range [3,4)  are "0". There is *one* consecutive zero, so why is the answer 0?

Comment: As a side note - from the queries, it looks like the range is `[l,r]`, not `[l,r)`. It's not too difficult - O(n) setup time, O(1) queries, but I'd like to see an attempt from your side first.

Comment: @ Dukeling: I know it's not too difficult, it's just I am not getting it :/

Comment: @Kevin: The binary array is 1-indexed. Updated my question.

Comment: In that case, the elements in the range [3,4) are "1". There is *one* consecutive one, so why is the answer 0? What makes it different from [5,6), which is "0" and has answer 1?

Comment: Hint: Regardless of the given range, the problem can be reduced to calculating `[1, x]` for some x twice (which can be done in O(1) if you do O(n) preprocessing).

Comment: This becomes more interesting if you also have an update operation that flips the bit at a given position.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with O(n) space complexity and O(log(n)) search time for each query. Calculate the counts for windows of size 1, 2, 4, .... For a given query you can find O(log(n)) windows (at most 2 windows of a particular size), summing which you can find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Dukeling said in the comments, you can preprocess in O(n) to compute an array B where B[x] contains the total number of consecutive digits seen in [1..r].

This allows a query in O(1) to find the number of consecutive digits in the range [l,r] by using the array to count the total number in the range [1,r] and subtracting the number in the range [1,l].

Python code:

```
def preprocess(A):
    last=A[0]
    B=[0,0]
    num_consecutive=0
    for a in A[1:]:
        if a==last:
            num_consecutive+=1
        B.append(num_consecutive)
        last=a
    return B

def query(B,l,r):
    return B[r]-B[l]

A=[0,1,1,0,0,0]
B=preprocess(A)

print query(B,1,3)
print query(B,5,6)
print query(B,1,5)
print query(B,3,6)
print query(B,3,4)
```